# in_array() keeps appending values if looping through db rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to identify every instance where a value in one array (needle) occurs in another array (haystack). `in_array()` seems to be my best option, and the code below works perfectly until I need to use it on rows fetched from a db - it keeps appending values instead of setting them each time it's called.

While I can't actually use `unset()` in this situation, I was surprised to discover that even that didn't seem to resolve the problem.

---

**UPDATE - Example of what's being returned**

I temporarily changed the db values so that $needles has only value per row (in order to make it possible to sort through the values filling up my screen ;-))

> 1. False;
> 2. False; False; True;
> 3. False; False; True; False; True;
> 4. False; False; True; False; True; False; True;
> 5. False; False; True; False; True; False; True; False;

---

**This works correctly** 
*(I've posted a functional example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3950296601aa37eb6d78356a8dc3727d7137697b))*

```
$needles = array('John', 'Alex');
$haystack = array('John','Alexander','Kim', 'Michael');

    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack) ) {
            $Match = 'True'; 
        }
        else {
            $Match = 'False'; 
        }
    }
```

**This keeps appending values - Edited to reflect the code I'm using**

```
$Customer_Categories_Arr = array('Casual','Trendy'); 

if ($stmt->columnCount()) {            
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
     $Product_Categories_Arr[]=$row["Taste_Category"];          
      // Use when column contains CSV
      // $Product_Categories_Arrx = explode(',', trim($Product_Categories_Arr[0]));          
      foreach ($Product_Categories_Arr as $Product_Category_Arr) {          
              if (in_array($Product_Category_Arr, $Customer_Categories_Arr)){   
                  $Matches_Product_Category = "True"; 
              } else {                                 
                  $Matches_Product_Category = "False";  
              }           
                  echo $Product_Category_Arr, ', ', $Matches_Product_Category, '; ';
        }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `$Match` isn't used in any way.

Comment: What values get appended to which array?

Comment: i don't get it, why are you gathering all the needles, why not use the single needle to search in that haystack

Comment: If I read this correctly you have a table with a column named "product_var", and this "product_var" contains an array (?). There's a lot more going on than in the first example (it is a table in which a column contains an array). Isn't every "product_var" a needle? (instead of being an array of needles -than it would be more like the first example)

Comment: @hobbs - I was just trying to keep the code clean :-) Obviously I'm using it ;-) At the moment I'm simply printing to the values to make sure it's working properly, and as soon as it's working I'll combine it with a big chunk of code which will allow me to assign weights to product recommendations based on the attributes that match

Comment: @MarkBaker - My bad ;-) It's appending it to the value for $Match

Comment: Nothing is being appended to the value for $Match in your code

Comment: @MarkBaker - That's what I would have thought ;-) But for some reason when it prints the value it's first printing every previous value :-(

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a spurious echo somewhere in your real code

Comment: @MarkBaker - I triple-checked ;-) But I'll definitely quadruple-check it with a fresh pair of eyes in the am

Comment: @spac3monk3y - Yes, it's representing a db column :-) In those instances where the db isn't normalized (and the column contains CSV), the values are first exploded & trimmed in order to work with in_array() (I'm using it for several of the haystacks, and it works perfectly there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are trying to do. But maybe this would help:

```php
$customerCategories = array('Casual', 'Trendy');
if( $stmt->columnCount() ){
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){
        $productCategoryRow = $row[ 'Taste_Category' ];
        // If it is not working, try uncommenting the next line
        // $productCategories = [];
        $productCategories = explode( ',', trim( $productCategoryRow ));

        $match = "False";
        foreach( $productCategories as $productCategory ){
            if( in_array( $productCategory, $customerCategories )){
                $match = "True";
            }
            echo $match . ";";
        }
    }
}
```

This prints your result on the screen every time a loop is done. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Sadly that still keeps appending the latest $match value

Comment: What do you mean with "appending the latest $match value"? Do you want the loop to stop if the needle isn't in the haystack? Or are you doing something in the if block where the match is true?

Comment: Because $match = "True"; is not appending anything. Maybe your real code contains something like $match .= "True"; ?

Comment: It doesn't, but I can post the complete code once I catch some zzz's  (it's 6am here ;-))

Comment: Yes, please. I think that would help :)

Comment: Thanks. So if I am understanding it correctly, you want this: looping over the table rows. In every loop you explode the table attribute in an array. Then for every element in that array you want to check wether it is in the other array or not. And every time you are checking a value, you want to print the outcome on the screen. But your problem is that it is not only checking every value, it is appending it to the first array an rechecking it every time. Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome :) Maybe you can vote my answer up? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second block of code to do what the first block of code (which works correctly) does, then the second block should look like this -

```
if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
       $needle =$row["product_var"];              
       $Match = "False";  
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack)){   
            $Match = "True"; 
        }                  
    }
}
```

You don't need do use the foreach because that is replaced by the while loop in the second block.

Comment: That fixed the 'appending' problem, but it also stopped updating the the value for $Match (since the 1st one returns 'False' they're all equaling 'False')

Comment: I have edited the answer to solve your second problem as well.

Comment: I love how much neater your code is :-D But sadly it's still causing the same problem :-(

Comment: Actually, I realised my edit didn't change anything :D But, I think both versions of the answer are logically correct. When are you actually checking or returning the value for $Match ?

Comment: @ChayaCooper could you explain what "keeps appending values" means? And maybe show the actual content of $haystack and your table? I think this answer should work, so there must be some vital difference between the example the the "real thing".

Comment: :-D I've tried it both within and immediately after the if/else statements :-(

Comment: Must be something to do with the values in $haystack and $needle then. Are you sure one of your needles is actually present in haystack for the $Match to be true?

Comment: @spac3monk3y - I just updated the question to include that ;-)

Comment: @v2solutions.com - Definitely :-D I'm testing it with 11 rows, of which 6 return true values :-)

Comment: @spac3monk3y - I just added the code that I'm currently using :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try an solve this. I think the problem is with:

```
$needles[]=$row["product_var"];
```

I think this should be:

```
$needles=$row["product_var"];
```

The column "product_var" contains an CSV (as you mentioned), so I can make an example like this:

```
$csv = "jake;john;alex;kim";
```

An example with brackets ($needles[]):

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $needles[] = explode(";", $csv);
    echo(count($needles).", ");
}
```

returns:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

**edit (for more explaining):**

if I use print_r I see the array expanding, exactly how it happens in your example:

step 1: it **adds** an array to $needles with values ('jake','john','alex','kim')

step 2: it **adds** an array to $needles, so it contains 2x the values ('jake','john','alex','kim')

step 3: it **adds** an array to $needles, so it contains 3x the values ('jake','john','alex','kim')

etc.

Now without the brackets ($needles):

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $needles = explode(";", $csv);
    echo(count($needles).", ");
}
```

This returns:

```
4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
```

And every time the array simply contains the values ('jake','john','alex','kim') -which is what you want.

Could this explain the "expanding values"? (or am I just doing something really stupid which has nothing to do with your problem??)

**edit:**

If this is what is going wrong, then you are adding to an array, instead of only using the new array from $row["product_var"] (hope this makes any sense; it seems I am pretty bad at explaining what's happening).

Comment: Sadly, that's also preventing it from adding the current value to $match